# SQL Prevent multiple inserts at the same time for non-duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to prevent multiple inserts at the exact same time so I can prevent duplicate inserts. I have two tables:

1. Table B, this table has 4 columns `id`, `timeToken`, `tokenOrder` and `taken`.
2. Table A which I will be inserting into and that has `id`, `createDate` and `timeToken`.

What I am trying to do is prevent the `timeToken` in Table A not to have duplicate values in the case where multiple inserts are happening at the exact same time. I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue nvarchar

SELECT Top 1 @ReturnValue=timeToken FROM TableB WHERE taken = 0 Order By tokenOrder

Update TableB SET taken = 1 WHERE timeToken = @ReturnValue

INSERT INTO TableA Values(@ReturnValue, GETDATE())
```

Now that I think about it, is it possible to have my timeToken table in TableA auto increment with the timeToken from TableB?

**Table B sample data:**

```
id  timeToken   tokenOrder taken
1   1:00am      1          0
2   2:00am      2          0
3   3:00am      3          1
4   4:00am      4          0
5   5:00am      5          0
```

This is what I am expecting Table A to look like after 4 calls all at the exact same time that would cause duplicates (id starting at 5 - this could be because I have deleted old records).

**Table A sample data**:

```
id     createDate                 timeToken
5      2014-11-22 12:45:34.243    1:00am
6      2014-11-22 12:45:34.243    2:00am
7      2014-11-22 12:45:34.243    4:00am
8      2014-11-22 12:45:34.243    5:00am
```

Comment: Create cursor For "TableB"

Comment: have you tried combining your timeToken value plus the userid as value field?

Comment: What would be an example of a cursor @SinghKailash

Comment: What do you mean @Charlesliam

Comment: combine some value to your timeToken unique to that record. I said userid,  I only assume the sql you mention is triggered by a user.

Comment: Can I see an example of this @Charlesliam ?

Comment: You can prevent duplicate values with unique index.

Comment: **Please give an example!**

Comment: Is that sarcasm @GiorgosAltanis ? lol

Comment: How would I do that @VojtěchDohnal ?

Comment: `taken = true` - is this SQL Server? Because the boolean in SQL Server is called bit and has 0 or 1 values.

Comment: this is SQL, that was a typo, ill change it to 0 or 1

Comment: Why sarcasm? Providing an example of input and output helps people understand your problem, so they don't have to guess what exactly you mean or have to ask you too many questions.

Comment: Yup I get it, thought u were making fun of me cause I kept asking for an example

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part, otherwise I would have given more details... Anyway, can you come up with an example of what you want to have?

Comment: Each row in Table A to have a unique timeToken auto_incremented from the timeTokens in Table B where timeToken in Table B is not taken and then mark the taken in Table B as 1

Comment: Can't you give us an example dataset and the desired output?

Comment: Please edit your post with sample data as DDL + DML for all relevant tables and desired results.

Comment: added sample data and expected results.

Comment: There is another typo in your question, try to find it!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing but you can dispense with all of the mutex acrobatics if you just use an identity column and attach any particular attributes to that. You can throw a bunch of simultaneous inserts at a table with an identitiy column and they all get unique identity values. Then if you have special characteristics for a particular row, update it after your have reserved your identity values.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal found it

Comment: If you don't want to use an `identity` you can use a `sequence` instead. Is the basic logic that every new record gets a token 1 hours after the last one? Does it wraparound at some point?

Comment: no, that was just an example, they are 1:00, 1:10, 1:20, 1:30, 1:40, 2:00, 2:10, 2:20, 2:30, 2:40, 3:00, 3:10, 3:20, 3:30, 3:40 and so on till 8 so thats every 10 minutes, 5 per an hour, however some times are already marked as taken, how would I count for that?

Comment: hmmm that's tricky let me think about it.

Comment: So your problem can be stated as "Assign to each request the first available token. If multiple requests are issued simulataneously assign consecutive (available) tokens to them", am I correct?

Comment: I believe you are correct @GiorgosAltanis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite like this, this should ensure that you do not get the row with `taken=0` in TableB updated twice.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION    
    DECLARE @taken table(  
        id int NOT NULL,  
        timeToken nvarchar(max));  

    Update TOP (1) TableB 
       SET taken = 1 
       OUTPUT UPDATED.id, UPDATED.timeToken
       INTO @taken  
       WHERE timeToken = 
       (SELECT Top 1 timeToken FROM TableB WHERE taken = 0 Order By tokenOrder)

    INSERT INTO TableA 
    SELECT id, GETDATE(), timeToken
    FROM @taken    
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

See [SQL Server isolation levels](http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-server-isolation-levels-by-example) - read commited. READ COMMITTED is the default isolation level for the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

In the example I copy id from TableB to TableA, but it is not probably required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem in two steps:

*Step1:* Buffer all requests as soon as they arrive.

*Step2:* Periodically assign free tokens to the buffered requests.

**Preparation**

A `sequence` object will help resolve any order ambiguity:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Taken_Seq  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

An auxiliary table will play the role of the buffer:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer (
    requester uniqueidentifier, createdate datetime, seq_value bigint, id int);
```

I will also use a GUID to refer to the different processes asking for a token (requesters):

```
ALTER TABLE TableA add Requester uniqueidentifier;
```

**Solution outline**

As soon as a request comes (identified by a GUID) buffer it consuming the next sequence value, like this (here I use newid() to get a GUID, your application should have already assigned one to your request):

```
declare @seq bigint;

SELECT @seq = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Taken_Seq;
insert buffer values (newid(), getdate(), @seq, null);
```

Suppose now that three such requests arrive simultaneously, as in:

```
declare @seq bigint;

SELECT @seq = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Taken_Seq;
insert buffer values (newid(), getdate(), @seq, null);

SELECT @seq = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Taken_Seq;
insert buffer values (newid(), getdate(), @seq, null);

SELECT @seq = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Taken_Seq;
insert buffer values (newid(), getdate(), @seq, null);
```

The contents of the `buffer` table will then look like this:

```
requester                            createdate              seq_value            id
------------------------------------ ----------------------- -------------------- -----------
109B560C-155C-40BD-A13A-59D21EBEB1F8 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 31                   NULL
FAC00C2E-14AA-4502-AB5C-DDD756914653 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 32                   NULL
E95889C3-E291-4A1C-A7E8-0B8CC53D4D7B 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 33                   NULL
```

Next we can match each buffered request to a token. This will be done by assinging an `id` value to each request in our buffered table:

```
; with a as 
(select rn =row_number() over (order by seq_value), *
from buffer 
where id is null), 
b as
(
select rn=row_number() over (order by tokenOrder), *
from TableB 
where taken = 0
)
update buffer set buffer.id = b.id 
from buffer 
join a on buffer.requester = a.requester 
join b on a.rn = b.rn
```

This is now how our `buffer` table looks like:

```
requester                            createdate              seq_value            id
------------------------------------ ----------------------- -------------------- -----------
109B560C-155C-40BD-A13A-59D21EBEB1F8 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 31                   1
FAC00C2E-14AA-4502-AB5C-DDD756914653 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 32                   2
E95889C3-E291-4A1C-A7E8-0B8CC53D4D7B 2017-04-05 11:17:35.127 33                   3
```

Join the `buffer` table with `TableB` to find the tokens:

```
select buffer.requester, tableB.* from buffer join tableB on buffer.id= tableB.id
```

Mark the tokens as taken:

```
update TableB set taken = 1 from buffer where buffer.id = TableB.id
```

Finally, insert into `TableA`:

```
insert TableA (requester, createdate, timeToken)
select buffer.requester, buffer.createdate, TableB.timeToken 
from buffer join TableB on buffer.id = TableB.id
```

**Note:**
Obviously some of these steps must be contained within a single transaction